# Alternate columns background for dynamic columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

A have a `DataGrid` with `ItemsSource` set to a `DataTable` and with `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

How can I make alternate columns background in it? Each solution I saw applies to static columns only.

I don't use code behind so XAML-only solution preferred but I will be happy with every valuable answer.

Comment: Side note: Why setting `DataContext` and not `ItemsSource`?

Comment: You're right, I'm using `ItemsSource` in fact :) I copied the code from wrong place (I also have my own control derived from `DataGrid` and I use `DataContext` there). I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert from `DataGridCell.Column.DisplayIndex` to a boolean that alternates between odd and even column indices.

I utilize the converter from the Extended WPF Toolkit here, but it should be easy enough to write you own.

```
<xcdg:IndexToOddConverter x:Key="oddConverter"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Column.DisplayIndex,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Converter={StaticResource oddConverter}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AlternatingColumnBackgroundBrush}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You probably want to utilize a transparent background, so that alternating row colors and selection colors are still shining through the cell color.

Comment: @bpiec I'm 100% certain that I have the free version... but as stated, it's just a converter that takes an index and returns a boolean... easy enough to write your own if you don't have a premade available. Note it's part of the `http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid` namespace, not the `http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit` one.

Comment: I am marking this answer as accepted since it was first and really works. I made my own `IndexToOddConverter` but one can use solution provided by @mm8. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create your own converter class:

```
public class OddConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        return (int)value % 2 != 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

---

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:OddConverter x:Key="oddConverter" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Column.DisplayIndex,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Converter={StaticResource oddConverter}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Silver"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Or you could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event:

```
int index = 0;
private void dgrData_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (index++ % 2 != 0)
    {
        e.Column.CellStyle = dgrData.Resources["oddCellStyle"] as Style;
    }
}
```

---

```
<DataGrid Name="dgrData" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}"  AutoGeneratingColumn="dgrData_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="oddCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Silver"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```